# Why is the image from my canvas getting downloaded without the text overlay?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**Requirement:**

1. Users can type in text that goes as an overlay on top of an image.
2. Users can download the image with the overlay.

To do this, I'm drawing the image onto the canvas, filling with the text and then setting the link's `href` to the canvas's dataURL.

**Findings:**

1. I can see the text overlay on the image in the canvas just fine.
2. If I right-click on the canvas and download the image, I can see the text overlay just fine.
3. If I click on the link, I see the original image **without** the text overlay.

What did I miss?

Here's the snippet:

```js
var imgURL = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Neptune_Full.jpg';

function loadCanvas(dataURL) {
  var canGreeting = document.getElementById('canGreeting');
  var context = canGreeting.getContext('2d');

  // load image from data url
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    context.font = "20px sans-serif";
    context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    var arrayOfLines = $('#txtGreetingText').val().split('\n');
    var y = 50;
    var i = 0;
    $(arrayOfLines).each(function() {
      context.fillText(arrayOfLines[i], 50, y);
      i++;
      y += 30;
    });
  };
  imageObj.src = dataURL;
  lnkDownload.download = "card.jpg";
  lnkDownload.href = imageObj.src;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadCanvas(imgURL);
  $("#txtGreetingText").on("keydown", function(e) {
    loadCanvas(imgURL);
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 420px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="txtGreetingText" id="txtGreetingText"></textarea>
<br/>
<canvas id="canGreeting" width="480" height="480"></canvas>
<br/>
<a id="lnkDownload">Download this card</a>
```

Comment: @Downvoter, I'm happy to improve the question. Could you please comment on what should be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href` attribute should be pointing to base64 encoded image of the canvas source. Do this:

```
$(arrayOfLines).each(function() {
  context.fillText(arrayOfLines[i], 50, y);
  i++;
  y += 30;
});
// udpate link to image
// Grab base64 encoded URL
var url = canGreeting.toDataURL("image/png;base64;");
lnkDownload.href = url;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer in 4 minutes, once the system allows.

Comment: The parameter you pass to toDataURL is invalid. It will anyway use the default png encoding, but you must not set this I don't know what you think it is`;base64;`